# Spectrum of compact operators on infinite dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely the spectrum of compact operators on infinite dimensional Banach spaces. In the text, the author gives the following proposition:

> **Proposition A**: Let $T\colon X\to X$ be a compact operator and $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Then $T_\lambda:=T-\lambda\text{Id}$ is one-to-one if and only if it is onto.

I completely understand **Proposition A**. The author then gives the main theorem of this chapter:

> **Theorem 1**: For any compact operator $T\colon X\to X$ in an infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ we have
> $$
> \sigma(T)=\{0\}\cup\sigma_p(T).
> $$

The author does not give any proof, so I assume **Proposition A** must, in some sense, be the proof. So my question is, does my proof below work?

*Proof*. It's clear that $\sigma(T)\supseteq\{0\}\cup\sigma_p(T)$. Take $\lambda\in\sigma(T)\setminus\{0\}$. By definition this means $T_{\lambda}$ is not invertible. By **Proposition A** it follows that $T_{\lambda}$ is neither one-to-one or onto. Since it's not one-to-one, it follows that $\text{ker}T_{\lambda}\neq\{0\}$. Thus $\lambda\in\sigma_p(A)$, and so $\sigma(T)\setminus\{0\}\subseteq\sigma_p(T)\implies\sigma(T)\subseteq\{0\}\cup\sigma_p(T)$.

Comment: What book is  this? No compact operator in an infinite dimesnional Banach space can be bijective.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Eidelman-milman-tsolomitis, functional analysis book. Maybe I've made some odd mistake...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Let me edit the post actually to what the book says. EDIT: I've edited the said **proposition A**, which I believe to be straight from the book. How is it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$o \in \sigma (T)$ because a compact operator in an infinite dimensional space cannot be invertible. By definition $\sigma_p(T) \subset \sigma(T)$. So we only have to show that $\sigma(T) \subset \{0\} \cup \sigma_p(T)$. So take  $\lambda \neq 0$ is the spectrum. Suppose  it does not belong to   $\sigma_p(T)$. Then $\lambda $ is not an eigen value so there is no non-zero vector $x$ with $Tx=\lambda x$. Thus $(T-\lambda I)x=0$ implies $x=0$. This means $T-\lambda I$ is one-to-one. By Proposition A it follows that $T-\lambda I$ is also onto. By Open Mapping Theorem it follows that $T-\lambda I$ has  a bounded inverse. But this contradicts our assumption that $\lambda \in \sigma (T)$.

Comment: In order to apply the Open Mapping Theorem we need that $T-\lambda I$ is bounded. How is this so? I know that $T$ is bounded, as it's compact. EDIT: I think $T-\lambda I$ is bounded since$$
||T-\lambda I||_X\leq||(T-\lambda I)(x)||_\text{op}||x||_X.
$$ Correct?

Comment: $\|T-\lambda I\| \leq \|T\|+|\lambda |$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't $\sigma_p(T)\cup \lbrace 0\rbrace=\sigma_p(T)$? Because $T$ is never injective. Otherwise it would posses a left inverse $S$. Such that (if $S$ is continous) $ST=I_X$ is compact, which would be false. Or is it not true in generall that this left inverse must be continuous?